# How to add dots between numbers using preg_replace?

Tags: php, numbers, preg-replace, twilio, number-formatting

I'm using a phone API called Twilio and it does text to voice. I'm making a phone number verification script that makes a 'PIN' and calls the user and gives them the pin thing is the voice API says it like the words, eg. PIN: 2001 would make it say "two thousand and one".

I was thinking if I put dots between them like PIN: 2001 -> 2.0.0.1 it would change that, I'm guessing I would have to `preg_replace` but I have no idea what expression would be used.

This is how I am generating my PIN:

```
$pin = substr(str_shuffle('1234567890'), 0, 4);
```

Comment: Please re-phrase your question -- I cannot figure out what you're trying to accomplish or why you're here for help. Thanks.

Comment: Hi Aaran, Twilio also offers this functionality automatically; see the documentation on OutgoingCallerIds, http://www.twilio.com/docs/api/rest/outgoing-caller-ids

Answer (score 5, accepted):

how about something like this:

```
implode(".", str_split($pin))
```